# Cool Animations on Android 2.3

Tags: android, animation, tween

How would I go about doing some reasonably cool animations on Android 2.3? I realize I'm asking what may sound like a silly question but I'm not able to use enough Bing-Fu (or enough Google-Fu) to find good info/examples on what types of animation is supported on 2.3. I'm specifically looking to do tweening and not any of the basic transition stuff a typical Bing search would turn up. So my question is, is it possible/reasonable to do tweened animations on 2.3? Is it possible to programmatically animate scale/position/alhpa channel of a view or a drawing? Any info is much appreciated!